# how to get nunit results to a database

Tags: c#, nunit, automated-tests

Hi I am trying to get the nunit results into a database while it is running.  So what I really need is a way to see if the test has passed or failed on the teardown so that I can write some code to insert values into the database based on if it passes or fails.

So is it possible to get this information in the teardown if the current running test is in a passing or failing state, as well as information such as test name and if it has failed the reason for failure.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, so I am finally getting around to giving this a shot.  For some reason I do not see my created addon in the nunit tools addon list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NUnit at or post 2.4.4, you can get the `TestResult` as it happens using [EventListeners](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=eventListeners&r=2.5.8) - you need to write your results to the DB from the `TestFinished` method.

```
void TestFinished(TestResult result);
```

The name of the test will be that of the most recent `TestStarted` call:

```
void TestStarted(TestName testName);
```

To do this you have to implement an [NUnit addin](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunitAddins&r=2.5.8) that implements the `EventListeners` interface.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for.  Is there a good article on how to do this?  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I just edited the answer - you have to make your own NUnit addin with that interface.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to see results as they happen, or at the end? If you just want to see them at the end, you could get NUnit to write them to an XML file:

```
nunit-console /xml:console-test.xml nunit.tests.dll
```

You could then write a program to parse the XML and load it into a database.

To see test results as they happen, you could write your own NUnit log plugin.